# Import multiple files using paths stored in variables into SQLite tables in C

Tags: c, sqlite

I have the following code:

```
char const* const fileName = argv[1]; 
FILE* file = fopen("/home/tariq/Desktop/domainlist.txt", "r"); 
  char path[256] ;
  char subpath[128];

  while (fgets(path, sizeof(path), file)) {
        if (fscanf(file,"%s" ,path)==1){
            memcpy(subpath, &path[23], 30);
            subpath[strlen(subpath)-8] = '\0';
          printf("Path %s ***** SubPath %s\n", path, subpath);

        }
  }
```

As you can see, the while loops on the domainlist.txt file (which contains a list of other text files). in the variable path I store each path from the domainlist.txt and in the variable subpath I store some text from the original path. My question is that I want (instead of the printf line) to create SQLite table with a name from variable the subpath and import the data from the file in variable path.
The SQLite database is already created and a connection is open, I just want to create tables and import data into them. I tried to use termsql but all I could do is to create separate database from each file, which I don't want, I want one DB but different tables.

I hope I could describe my case correctly.

Thanks

**EDIT**

The content of the files to be added to the db tables are just a list of URLs. Example below:

the file (domainlist.txt) contains a list of paths,

Example of a path:
Path (which will be in the path variable):
/home/tariq/Desktop/BL/ads/domains.txt

Subpath variable (which I want to be the table name):
ads

Content of file "domains.txt" in the path above is just a list of URLs.

Comment: Just so I'm clear, you have a list of filenames and you want to store the contents of those files in a table?

Comment: Yes I have a list of filenames and I want to store the content of each file from the list in separate table, the table name should be from the variable subpath

Comment: You should explain (In the question, not a comment!) precisely how to derive the table names and what the contents of the files you want to import look like, with example data exactly as it would it appear in the files.

Comment: I did it now ..

Comment: Much better, thanks. - Does this *have* to be in C? It's a few lines of shell, and while doing it in C isn't difficult, it is tedious and more work.

Comment: Well, since I get all the paths and variables in C so I'd prefer if it can be in C too so I can just do it in the same script file, but if there's any other way that can be efficient (because URL files are relatively large) it would also be good. Thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you haven't gotten it working yet, looking at that bit of code in your question makes me suspect you're not that strong at C yet, because there's some strange bits that don't really make any sense (Why are you reading a line with `fgets()` and then immediately using `fscanf()` to read a single word into the same variable you just read a line into? Especially when your input seems to have one filename per line? And that memcpy() will break badly if you try using files in different directories.)

That's why I suggested using a shell script. With all your information in files, it's just so much easier even if you're fluent in C.

Here's a bash-specific one:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
database=test.db
domainsfile=domainlist.txt
coproc sqlite3 -batch -list "$database"
echo "PRAGMA journal_mode = TRUNCATE;" >&${COPROC[1]}
while read filename; do
    d=$(dirname "$filename")
    tablename=$(basename "$d")
    cat >&${COPROC[1]} <<EOF
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "$tablename"(url TEXT);
.import "$filename" "$tablename"
COMMIT;
EOF
done <$domainsfile
echo .quit >&${COPROC[1]}
wait $COPROC_PID
```

and a less efficient (Because it runs a new instance of the sqlite3 shell per table, instead of using a single one for all of them) but more generic portable sh version:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
database=test.db
domainsfile=domainlist.txt
while read filename; do
    d=$(dirname "$filename")
    tablename=$(basename "$d")
    sqlite3 -batch -list "$database" <<EOF
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "$tablename"(url TEXT);
.import "$filename" "$tablename"
EOF
done <$domainsfile
```

However, some hints for a C version:

For each filename in domainlist.txt, extract the table name portion (The POSIX `dirname()` and `basename()` functions would be useful). Then create the table with something like:

```
char *errmsg;
char *table_stmt = sqlite3_mprintf("CREATE TABLE \"%s\"(url TEXT);", tablename);
if (sqlite3_exec(db, table_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errmsg) != SQLITE_OK) {
  // Error handling
}
sqlite3_free(table_stmt);
```

and import the contents of the current file with something like:

```
char *insert_stmt = sqlite3_mprintf("INSERT INTO \"%s\"(url) VALUES (?)", tablename);
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, insert_stmt, -1, &stmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
  // Error handling
}

// Open the current file
// In a loop that reads each line in it:
sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, line, -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
if (sqlite3_step(stmt) != SQLITE_DONE) {
  // Error handling
}
sqlite3_reset(stmt);

// After importing the file:
sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
```

You'll probably want to wrap each table import in a transaction, as in the bash example, or even the entire thing, for performance reasons.

Comment: Man I really appreciate your effort, this is amazing what you replied to me with. And you're right, I'm not experienced with C, and the reason I use `fgets()` followed by `fscanf()` is that I couldn't find a way to assign the path into a variable and a single word from the path in another variable. And what alternative you can suggest for solving that ? (if you can answer of course).
And now I'm honestly confused, should I proceed with C and continue with the solution you gave me or switch to bash script. And thank you so much again.

Comment: Problems are all solved now, the code is perfectly working as you suggested. Thank you for your help :))